# How to log requested payload details on 401 Unauthorized error when try to POST in springboot API

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-401

I have a situation I would need to know the requested payload details when the POST request got 401 Unauthorized error.
I am thinking we will NOT be able to capture the payload when the request has NOT made it to the API endpoint due to Unauthorized error. It will be filtered out before hitting this endpoint.

I am using Springboot 2.1.6

My controller method as below

```
@PostMapping(value = "/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<PayloadResponse> processPayload(@RequestBody String payload) {
    logger.info("Received a payload: {}", payload);
}
```

Are there any ways we can log this payload somehow even on 401 error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any of SpringMVC mechanisms to catch and log this kind of error because it happens before going in MVC stack. @ControlerAdvice won't do a thing.

You can extend `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and config it by

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint())

    }
}
```

extend it like this

```
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
                         AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException {

        res.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        res.setStatus(401);
        res.getWriter().write(JsonUtil.getWriteMapper().writeValueAsString(
                new ErrorRestResponse(authException,false,""))); //This is my custom error response
        
        // You can put logging code around here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [@ControllerAdvice](http://zetcode.com/springboot/controlleradvice/) to handle all kinds of requests and read their payloads if supplied, and give back the appropriate response.