# How to handle 401 unauthorized error in Springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-401

I need to log 401 unauthorized errors in my Springboot application.
I wanted to log this for a certain end point in my app since its unauthorized error I know this attempt will be caught when invoking the api at the beginning itself.

Are there anyways I can keep track of this in spring boot?
I tried through WebSecurityConfig but didnt help.

I am using springboot 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my answer for other question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63853203/3849555

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways I can think of, but probably there are more

1. use custom `@ExceptionHandler` method in your controller and make it sensitive to `UnauthorizedException.class`
2. Use `Filter` to introspect into request/response - and log whatever you want in case of response beeing 401.

Answer (score -1):

You can get hold of the authentication entry point and handle some 401 logic in the http
security config:

```
  .authenticationEntryPoint((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
                log.warn(e.getMessage());
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
            })
```